# How to get the value of a textbox in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

HTML:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" value="" placeholder="Search" id="searchB" class="styledTB searchB floatLeft" />
```

C#:

```
string strSMain;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbSearchMain = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)sender;

    strSMail = tbSearchMain.text; // gives me the following error: Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.site_master' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

    strSMain = searchB.text; //.Text is not an option for me
}
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

I am creating a web application. And the control is in the MasterPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<input id="searchB" x:Name="searchB" type="text" runat="server" value="" placeholder="Search" class="styledTB searchB floatLeft" />
```

The id attribute is used client side. `x:Name` is used for server side manipulation

Comment: I had a brain freeze. I can just use `searchB.Value`;

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but no textbox will be sender for Page_Load() function.

Check about DataContext Property and how it works.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/

Comment: I took that out of another page but that didn't work unfortunately. Thank you for the response. +1 for the information.